# How to insert given key-value pair at a given index?

Tags: java, data-structures, symbol-table

How would I insert a key value pair into an array at a specific index? Thats the code I have so far but it's not passing my test. it is failing at:

```
Fails on the below key value pairs:
size = 1, key-value pairs = (ZS, 160)
Failure in putting (ZS, 160) into the following symbol table:
size = 0, key-value pairs =
```

---

```
public class SortedArrayST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
    private static final int MIN_SIZE = 2;
    private Key[] keys;      // the keys array
    private Value[] vals;    // the values array
    private int N = 0;       // size of the symbol table


    private void insert(Key key, Value val, int r) {
        // TODO
        //shift to the left
        if (keys == null) return;
        int i = rank(keys[r]);
        if (i == N || keys[i].compareTo(keys[r]) != 0){
            return;
        }
        for (int j = i; j < N-1; j++)  {
            keys[j] = keys[j+1];
            vals[j] = vals[j+1];
        }
            N--;
             keys[N] = null;
             vals[N] = null;        
}}
```

Comment: It looks like N starts at zero and only gets decremented.  I imagine keys[N] wouldn't like a negative index.

Comment: You might look at LinkedHashMap, an order-preserving key/value map for ideas.  It can't insert at a specific position, but it might give you some food for thought.

Comment: I don't see keys and values being initialized, so would keys == null always be true?

Comment: Try to envision an array.  If it has 10 elements and you need to insert something at the 5th element, some of the elements will need to be shifted over.  Which way will they move?  Left or right?

Comment: @HankD I think we can assume that (1) there are other methods in the class that the OP isn't showing us, and (2) this is a class assignment so using a library collection is not allowed.

Comment: First of all I would like to point out that for maintaining KEY-VALUE pair, You should go for `MAP`s. And because you want the functionality of inserting a key-value pair at certain index, you need to have an ordered map. So I would recommend using a `LinkedHashMap` for this as it maintains insertion order.